# Laravel route throws NotFoundHttpException

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm looking for some help. I've searched on other topics, and saw what is the problem approximatively, but didn't succeed to fix it on my code.
Now the question is: I have NotFoundHttpException when i try to submit an update on my code.

Here is the Controller and my function update

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\T_collaborateurs_table;

class testing extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $user = T_collaborateurs_table::all();
        return view ("read", compact("user"));
    }
    public function create()
    {
        return view("create");
    }

    public function store(Request $Request)
    {
        T_collaborateurs_table::create(Request::all());

        return redirect("index");
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        $user=T_collaborateurs_table::find($id);
        return view("show", compact("user"));
    }

    public function edit($id)
    {
        $user=T_collaborateurs_table::find($id);
        return view("update", compact("user"));
    }

    public function update(Request $Request, $id)
    {
        $user = T_collaborateurs_table::find($id);
        $user->update(Request::all());

        return redirect("index");
    }
}
```

Now the routes

```
Route::get("create", "testing@create");
Route::post("store", "testing@store");
Route::get("index", "testing@index");
Route::get("show/{id}", "testing@show");
Route::get("edit/{id}", "testing@edit");
Route::patch("update/{id}", "testing@update");
```

And now the view update.blade.php

```
<body>
    {{Form::model($user, ['method'=>'patch', 'action'=>['testing@update',$user->id]])}}

    {{Form::label('Id_TCa', 'ID')}}
    {{Form::text('Id_TCa')}}
    {{Form::label('Collaborateur_TCa', 'collab')}}
    {{Form::text('Collaborateur_TCa')}}
    {{Form::label('Responsable_TCa', 'resp')}}
    {{Form::text('Responsable_TCa')}}

    {{Form::submit("update")}}
    {{Form::close()}}
</body>
```

[Here the route:list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqbSe.jpg)

I'm sorry if my words are not very understable...
Thank you all for your time.

Comment: why don't use put against patch?

Comment: Can you run `php artisan route:list` and post the results?

Comment: Hi Luis, in fact i used a tutorial on internet, i understand a bit of Laravel, but i tried to improve myself. And if i change the method into "put" i don't know what change in my code to make it work :@ I just have to change the method in my view and in my route to do it ?

Comment: If you are going to use the same basic methods that a resource controller uses, I would suggest just using a resource controller instead.  https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#resource-controllers

Comment: @Sandeesh I edit my thread to add my route:list, tanks!

Comment: @Derek Thanks i take a look on it

Answer (score 5):

```
{{Form::model($user, ['method'=>'PATCH', 'action'=>  ['testing@update',$user->id]])}}
```

Or try to use 'route' instead of 'action',to use 'route' you just need a little edit in your update route.

```
Route::patch("update/{id}", array('as' => 'task-update', 'uses'=>'testing@update'));
```

in your view:

```
 {{Form::model($user, ['method'=>'PATCH', 'route'=>['task-update',$user->id]])}}
```

And please follow the convention of class naming. Your class name should be 'TestingController' or 'Testing'.

Comment: Thank you molagbal for your help, i tried it but the same error remains.

Comment: Oops,edit your update function, public function update(Request $Request)
    {
        $user = T_collaborateurs_table::find($Request->id);
        $user->update(Request::all());

        return redirect("index");
    }

Comment: I keep your new route and your view in your first response + your new function but the problem is still here. 
Maybe i can show you my Model ? Or it's not the problem aniway ?
Again! thank for your time.

Comment: Ok then Accept this as Answer..:)

Answer (score 1):

You could try method spoofing by adding

```
{{ method_field('PATCH') }}
```

in your form and change the form method to `POST`

```
{{ Form::model($user, ['method'=>'POST', 'action'=>['testing@update', $user->id]]) }}
```

add the id as an hidden field

```
{{ Form::hidden('id', $user->id) }}
```

access the id in the controller as

```
public function update(Request $Request)
{
    $id = Input::get('id');
    $user = T_collaborateurs_table::find($id);
    $user->update(Request::all());

    return redirect("index");
}
```

also need to modify your route accordingly

```
Route::patch("update", "testing@update");
```

Comment: something like this ? it still doesn't work...

{{Form::model($user, ['method'=>'patch', 'action'=>['testing@update',$user->id]])}}

{{ csrf_field() }}
{{ method_field('PATCH') }}
{{Form::label('Id_TCa', 'ID')}}
{{Form::text('Id_TCa')}}
{{Form::label('Collaborateur_TCa', 'collab')}}
{{Form::text('Collaborateur_TCa')}}
{{Form::label('Responsable_TCa', 'resp')}}
{{Form::text('Responsable_TCa')}}


{{Form::submit("update")}}
{{Form::close()}}

Comment: {{ Form::model($user, ['method'=>'POST', 'action'=>['testing@update',$user->id]]) }}
{{ method_field('PATCH') }}

I try like this but new error : Error exception missing argument 2 for App\Http\Controllers\testing::update()

So this line on my Controller "public function update(Request $Request, $id)"

Comment: Can you post the generated html of the form?

Comment: No sorry wrong alert, the problems remains the same, NotFoundHttpException, You still want the generated html before the error ?

Comment: the source code of the generated form before error please

Comment: https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2017/22/1496217746-essai2.png
This one ? I have this too, if it can help you

https://www.noelshack.com/2017-22-1496211951-reseau.png

Comment: The id isn't getting passed in the action

Comment: New error now: "FatalThrowableError" with text "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::input()"

Comment: Instead of `$Request->input('id')` you could use `Input::get('id')` just make sure to import `use Input` in your controller

Comment: At first i had the answer class Input Not found, so i take a look on my facades and there is no Input class.
I add the class 'Input' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::class, on my config file, but new problem now:
"Fatal Throwable error" "Call to a member function update() on null"

Comment: Can you do an `dd($id)` in your controller to check whether it is receiving the id, if yes do an `dd($user)` to check whether the user object is returned

Comment: I try to put "dd($id)" in my function but nothing appears, in my html page, did i make somthing wrong ?

Comment: Have you added the hidden input field? Does this show up in your form `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="1">` ?

Comment: Yes i try to use with and withou the hidden input field, but nothing appears, i have to change something on my view ? I just put the dd $id in my function edit and update .

Comment: You need to place the hidden input field as the id is being passed using the hidden input field and is accessible in your controller as  `$id = Input::get('id');`

Comment: I did this in my controller
        $id = Input::get('id');
        dd($id);
        $user = T_collaborateurs_table::find($id);
        $user->update(Request::all());



        return redirect("index");

and this in my view

{{ Form::model($user, ['method'=>'POST', 'action'=>['testing@update',$user->id]]) }}
{{ method_field('PATCH') }}
{{ Form::hidden('id', $user->id) }}

Comment: can you post the results of `Request::input('id')` from your controller?

Comment: I succeed, i explain to you.
In my other function i use $id (you can see it in my edit function and my show function) but my id in my DB is called Id_TCa. So i make with your help "$id = Input::get('Id_TCa');" and now my update is working.
I just don't understand why in my other function $id works, but in my update function i need to use $Id_TCa, is certainly because i'm a noob :p

Comment: In your other functions , `$id` works because it obtains the `id` from the route while in the update method, the id wasn't send via the route. You could replace the `action` method with `route` as @molagbal explained to pass the id in the url so that could be accessed as a route parameter

Comment: Oh ok i understand now...
So for the other one just follow the insctructions to @linktoahref, but use the name of your ID in your DB with function update
Thanks a lot to you linktoahref, it's thanks to you and your dd($id) i saw the id was null, so i change to Id_TCa

Answer (score 0):

Try using on `function update`:

```
return redirect()->route('index');
```